# WordPress automatically downloaded a theme?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to figure out if I've been hacked. I made a custom WordPress theme, named 'claremont'. Somehow it got replaced with a downloaded theme, also named 'claremont'. Does WordPress ever automatically do this?

I'm not running any plugins that I'd suspect would do this - just Gravity Forms, The Events Calendar, BBPress and addon plugins for those. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a custom theme and that theme has the same name as the theme available in WordPress.org themes repository (and 'claremont' exists there: https://wordpress.org/themes/claremont/), and if the WP.org theme has the higher version number, WordPress will include this theme for the update.

But, in a normal case, themes are not auto updated, so you have either run the update without checking what is updated, or your WordPress is set to auto update themes too.

It is always a good idea to check theme name in WP.org before using it or add some unique identifier in the theme name to avoid name conflict issues.